# Making an anchor with JavaScript called from backing bean

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I know it will sound crazy, but I'm looking for a way to make an anchor (like `<a href="#someId">`) that could be called from a backing bean method using JavaScript. For some reasons I need to make it this way, with a `commandButton` that is set with `ajax="false"`.

I'm trying something like this:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("JAVASCRIPT THAT FOCUSES MY PAGE ON A HTML COMPONENT GIVEN ITS ID");
```

The idea is that even without ajax I could render my page showing it back to where it was.

Any ideas? It might be a simple JavaScript command, but I'm not really into JavaScript and I didn't find any simple solution that works...

Comment: You cannot have a backingbean return/execute javascript in a non-ajax call

Comment: and **I didn't find any simple solution that works...** what solutions did you try? what did not work?

Comment: and so you found a complex solution that worked?

Comment: None of my previous tries actually worked, guys. But BalusC answer did. So thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)'s hash fragment.

In JavaScript:

```
location.hash = "someId";
```

In JSF/PrimeFaces (if really necessary):

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("location.hash='someId'");
```

The alternative would be to send a redirect:

```
externalContext.redirect(request.getRequestURI() + "#someId");
```

Comment: Thank you BalusC! Both your answers worked here (I didn't get the effect but due to other stuff I was supposed to do in my xhtml, but your answer was correct). I was also able to find the reason why ajax=true wasn't working and I ended solving my problem with a much better approach, but it was really good lesson anyway. Thank you very much!